# How to sort output of 2 same array data

Tags: python, arrays

I have :

- 1 array input (A)
- 1 array (B) for compare (comparing A to B)
- 1 array output

> ```
> I want the data to be like this :
>     data array A    data array B      output array
>     Alpha           Alpha             Alpha*
>     Delta           Beta              Beta
>     Fanta           Charlie           Charlie    
>                     Delta             Delta*
>                     Echo              Echo
>                     Fanta             Fanta*
> ```

What I want is, whenever there is a same data in array A and B, "the data" marked by *.
I'm sorry if my english is not easy to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want in this do you want to merge the two arrays with same element appearing once ?
list(set(arr1 + arr2))

Comment: Please include what you have tried already to give us a start. SO is not a code writing service that will provide code from scratch.

Comment: The question is not clear to me: do you want the output array to be a union of the input arrays, but the items that show up in the intersection to be modified to have a '*' concatenated to them ?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is not clear, I have modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right: you want to merge two arrays, and each element should appear only once (assuming sorted lists `a` and `b`):

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

a = ['Alpha', 'Delta', 'Fanta']
b = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo']

c = [v for v, _ in groupby(merge(a, b))]

print(c)
```

Prints:

```
['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Fanta']
```

---

EDIT: To mark duplicate elements with `*`, you can do:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

# assuming sorted `a` and `b`:
a = ['Alpha', 'Delta', 'Fanta']
b = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Fanta']

c = ['{}*'.format(v) if len(list(g)) > 1 else v for v, g in groupby(merge(a, b))]

print(c)
```

Prints:

```
['Alpha*', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Delta*', 'Echo', 'Fanta*']
```

Comment: why not use list(set(a+b))

Comment: @DeepakTripathi `set()` is unordered structure and I think OP wants sorted output.

Comment: @AndrejKesely i run your code with a = ['Alpha', 'Delta', 'Fanta','Alpha'] (note 2 'alpha' in the array a) so it produce output as ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Fanta', 'Alpha']

Comment: @vgeorge I assumed sorted lists `a` and `b`. If they aren't sorted, you need to do `a = sorted(a)` and for `b` too before merge.

Comment: yea, i want a sorted output, and if there is a same data in array A and B, "the data" marked by *.

Comment: @infdefurlong I updated my answer. Now the duplicates are marked with `*`